# scanf() without field width limits can crash with huge input data

Tags: c, error-handling, cppcheck

So basically i want to input data in this way for example " string:%d:%d:%d ", if i use 
" %s:%d:%d:%d " it cant stop scanning the string until it finds a white space, but if i use this
" %[^:]:%d:%d:%d " its works but i get an error using cppcheck which is:

```
scanf() without field width limits can crash with huge input data. Add a field width specifier to fix this problem.

Sample program that can crash:

#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c[5];
    scanf("%s", c);
    return 0;
}

Typing in 5 or more characters may make the program crash. The correct usage here is 'scanf("%4s", c);', as the maximum field width does not include the terminating null byte.
```

I dont understand why so if someone could help me i would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Writing beyond the end of an array is undefined behavior. This is also why `gets()` was removed from the language. Always use a maximum length specifier with `%s` in scanf-family functions.

Comment: It is because you have only allocated 5 bytes in your array 'c'. And if you input any string that has at least 5 characters, it will write past the last byte allocated in 'c'. Remember that in C, strings always end with an extra '\0' character.

Comment: wait but for example i want to write this line ` bread:2:2:2 ` and if use ` %[^:]:%d:%d:%d ` it works it doesnt wait for a white space but if i use ` %s:%d:%d:%d ` it never ends until it finds a white space and i want to scan all of that in the same line

Comment: @MartimCorreia But `bread` can't be stored in `c` because `c` only has space for four characters, plus the NUL terminator. You might be better off using `strtok` to break the line into tokens. Then you can deal with the string separately from the numbers.

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
    int a, b, d;
    char c[5];
    if (scanf("%4[^:]:%d:%d:%d", c, &a, &b, &d) != 4)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
//for your program example use scanf("%4s",c);
```

this to avoid buffer over flow.

for your string , you can scan `4` chars(+1 for `\0`) ,otherwise you will pass boundaries of your array and this will lead to undefined behavior.

and if you want to store more data , for example bread in array `c` ,array should be `char c[6]`.

this is all about having enough space when you want to store data and adding this number in `scanf` like `scanf("%5s",c);` will prevent `scanf` to read more data than we have space for.